# rsync compression and how it works

Tags: linux, ubuntu, networking, rsync

I am using rsync to backup a large amount of files (on a Ubuntu Linux server) to a cloud network service over WebDav. Because my network speed is my bottle-necking factor, I thought I would use rsync -z (compression) to decrease the file size and hopefully this would lessen the bottleneck.

Anyway, while researching the purpose and use of rsync with compression I don't seem to find an answer to exactly what it is doing.

Basically it seems that rsync compresses the data, transfers it, then decompresses the data. However, it doesn't make a lot of sense to me that rsync decompresses the data after it has been sent to the cloud as that would require the cloud service to decompress the data, which i don't think is happening.

My question is, is does rsync with compressing  actually compress and decompress data that is sent over WebDav or FTP or some other network to network protocol? and if it does not help me, then in what scenario would the compression flag help me, local to local sync over USB 2.0 for example?

Comment: What is your rsync command? Yes, when no rsync server on remote, it is `cp`. Internally there is zlib in rsync (ancient algorithm with rsync modifications - http://code.metager.de/source/xref/rsync/zlib/README.rsync and special skip list of compressed file extenstions like gz/zip/.../bz2/7z to not doing recompression). Documented: http://code.metager.de/source/xref/rsync/doc/rsync.sgml#124 "-z ..  using a modified version of the @command{zlib} library." & https://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync "This program uses the excellent zlib compression library written by Jean-loup Gailly and Mark Adler."

Comment: Is your webdav mounted and looks like local folder (it may try to work with it like it is local folder - with lot of reading from it)? Why not to try to disable all compression and delta-methods of rsync (`-W, --whole-file            copy files whole (w/o delta-xfer algorithm)` of doc https://download.samba.org/pub/rsync/rsync.html)?

Comment: my rsync command is  `rsync -avzc /source/ /WebDAV_folder/`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Where is the WebDAV folder mounted?

If it is on the local machine, you just get additional overhead with no performance gains, since the CPU has to do double work to compress and immediately decompress before writing to the mounted folder, which is then transferred to the remote server using the WebDAV protocol.

`rsync` does the compression in-transit using `zlib`. If you are not doing differential transfers, then `scp` offers faster performance due to the additional overhead in the `rsync` algorithm used to compare changes in file directory trees (although `scp` does not have a compress-in-transit option).

Compression is not always the answer though. If your network is the bottleneck then it does speed up the process, but if your CPU% is maxed out, it will just make the process slower.

`rsync` does not compress compressed filetypes (since the performance tradeoff ratio in compressing those types of files is very low) such as `JPEG`, `LZO`, `LZMA/2`, `ZIP`, `GZIP`, etc.

Comment: "rsync does the compression in-transit using the LZO algorithm." - does it? There is zlib in doc https://download.samba.org/pub/rsync/rsync.html and lzo only is in list of skipped for compression file extensions list. And there is "This program uses the excellent zlib compression library". Also - did you check that local rsync starts both client and server and really sends tokens between them, or it just does all work in single process without any sending and without compression.

Comment: `rsync` will perform compression/decompression in-transit via IPC. This is much slower than without the -z flag which is effectively an `mv` command, so yes it starts both client/server and establishes a set of tokens. It does not operate in a single process.

With regards to using `zlib`, I confused the compression algorithm `rsync` uses with another protocol, so I apologize for that. I have edited the original post to reflect this.

Comment: So from what I understand of your answer, rsync compression over a locally mounted WebDAV doesn't do anything because it simply transfers it then decompresses it to the local folder and ultimately does not help the eventual network transfer.

Comment: @electricjelly yes

Comment: How does rsync detect compressed file types? Does it have a hard coded list of extensions to not compress or ...? I have a folder with lots of uncompressed files and a few compressed ones in a custom format and I'd like it to not compress the custom format ones.

Answer (score 4):

rsync since version [3.2.0](https://download.samba.org/pub/rsync/NEWS#3.2.0) supports more than zlib:

```
--compress, -z
       turn on compression
--compress-choice=STR, --zc=STR
       choose compression from lz4 (fastest), zstd, zlibx, zlib (slowest), none
--compress-level=NUM, --zl=NUM
       zlib and zstd can be tuned with compression level
       zlib from 1 (lowest) to 9 (highest), default 6
       zstd from -131072 to 22, default 3
```

Comment: I think --compress-level should be --zl not --lz